# Snaps: core18 and gnome-3-28-1804 on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: gnome, snap, 19.04

My notebook was initially running Ubuntu 18.10. Then I upgraded it to 19.04. When I run a `snap list` command, I get the following output:

```
Name               Version                     Rev   Tracking  Publisher     Notes
atom               1.36.1                      226   stable    snapcrafters  classic
core               16-2.38.1                   6818  stable    canonical✓    core
core18             20190409                    941   stable    canonical✓    base
gnome-3-28-1804    3.28.0-10-gaa70833.aa70833  40    stable    canonical✓    -
gtk-common-themes  0.1-16-g2287c87             1198  stable    canonical✓    -
mkvtoolnix-jz      33.1.0                      58    stable    jz            -
wine-platform      3.0.4-4.6                   128   stable    mmtrt         -
```

Do I really need `core18` and `gnome-3-28-1804` snaps in my notebook now that I am using Ubuntu 19.04 and GNOME 3.32.1?

Comment: Feel free to remove them. Apt won't do it for you - apt does not know about snaps.

Comment: I did remove _gnome-3-28-1804_. But, for _core18_ it says: **error: cannot remove "core18": snap "core18" is not removable**